# NSAttributedString initWithData:options:documentAttributes:error: is executing very slowly

Tags: ios, webkit, nsattributedstring

I was trying out the new iOS 7 APIs, and the following code would take over a minute to execute!

```
NSLog(@"start encoding");
NSString *htmlBody = @"<html><body>I am <b>bold</b> and <i>italic</i>";
NSStringEncoding encoding = NSUnicodeStringEncoding;
NSData *data = [htmlBody dataUsingEncoding:encoding];
NSDictionary *options = @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                          NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(encoding)};

NSAttributedString *body = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:data
                          options:options
                          documentAttributes:nil
                          error:nil];

NSLog(@"end encoding%@", body);
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After doing some investigation, I realized I was calling this method as part of a webview didFinishLoading callback. I believe this was causing some kind of live-locking or waiting with WebKit's threads. The solution was to have that webview method call its delegate (or other code) from inside a dispatch_aync block:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    if (self.successBlock) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //this success block eventually calls my NSAttributedString code above
             self.successBlock();     
        }); 
    }
}
```